# Solve equation for different values of x in r

Tags: r

I am trying to solve an equation for different values of x={0,1,....,53}.

The equation is:

```
y = -0.5*mean(sp_2$IMR) - 0.1*mean(sp_2$rev) - 0.04*x + 1.2*x*mean(sp_2$ebrd)
```

Note that IMR, rev and ebrd are vectors of 540 observations in the dataframe sp_2.

The result after solving this equations for all 54 x values should be an array of 54 y values. Which function should I use to achieve this and what is the complete syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using `seq` or the `:` notation:

```
x <- 0:53
y <- -0.5 * mean(sp_2$IMR) - 0.1 * mean(sp_2$rev) - 0.04 * x + 1.2 * x * mean(sp_2$ebrd)
```